# How to change the letter in a certain position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

```
secret = "gatos"

f = '*' * len(secret)

print(f)

print(f.replace(f[2], "t", ))
```

I realized that this "error" happens because I have strings that are the same, but I don't want them to change for `replace` to do what I want.

I want `replace` to change exactly in the position I want.